# Удалить элемент из цикла

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Добрый день!
Ситуация такая: вытаскиваю картинки из папки вот таким образом

```
var col = 0; 
for(i=1;i<22+1;i++)
{
  document.write('<div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-zoom-container"><img alt="" src="images/books/lookins/files/math/'+i+'.jpg" id="'+i+'"></div></div>'); 
  document.getElementById(i).onload = function() 
  {
    return;
    col++;
  }
}
```

Нужно чтобы определенная картинка (скажем 2.jpg) не вытаскивалась.
Как сделать? Помогите кто нибудь!

Comment: "не вытаскивалась" - ?? `if (i != 2) { ... }`

Comment: `return;
col++;` - unreachable code `col++;`

Comment: Спасибо! А как это должно выглядеть? Просто я чайник и сразу не соображу...

Comment: что "должно выглядеть"? Что значит "не вытаскивалась"? Представьте, что тут никто понятия не имеет, что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Ок! Имеется ввиду чтобы из определенной папки выбирались все картинки кроме 2.jpg. А выглядеть, имею ввиду готовый кусок кода потому как сам от этого очень далек, а сделать надо сейчас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var col = 0; 
for(i = 1; i < 22 + 1; i++) {
  if (i != 2) {
    document.write('<div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-zoom-container">' + 
      '<img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image'+i+'" id="'+i+'">' + 
      i + '</div></div>'); 
    document.getElementById(i).onload = function() {
      col++;
      console.log("col=",col);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.swiper-slide
{
  border:2px solid black;
}
.swiper-zoom-container
{
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Сейчас буду пробовать...

Comment: Супер! Все работает! Огромное спасибо! Скажите, а если кроме 2.jpg еще какую то картинку не выбирать (скажем 10.jpg) то куда это прописать?

Comment: Уже разобрался. Еще раз СПАСИБО!